# How do I return a user as a string using their username with the Discord.js API?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to make a command called "embed" where a user can type !embed {another users name} to get an embed containing the mentioned users information. If they do not mention a user, then an embed containing their information will be sent to the channel.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
case 'embed': // Code for embeds
  if(arg.length > 1) {
    let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members;
    const embedChoice = new Discord.RichEmbed() // Use RichEmbed for sending embeds, not MessageEmbed, which is for recieving embeds
      .setColor(0x8d1e1e) 
      .setTitle('User Information')
      .addField('Player Name', mentionedMember, true)
      .addField('Player Nickname', 
    Client.users.find(mentionedMember).nickname, true)
      .addField('Current Server', message.guild.name)
      .setThumbnail(Client.users.find(mentionedMember).avatarURL)
      .setFooter('Bot made by sultana');
    message.channel.send(embedChoice);
    } else {
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed() // Use RichEmbed for sending embeds, not MessageEmbed, which is for recieving embeds
      .setColor(0x8d1e1e) 
      .setTitle('User Information')
      .addField('Player Name', message.author.username, true)
      .addField('Player Nickname', message.member.nickname, true)
      .addField('Current Server', message.guild.name)
      .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL)
      .setFooter('Bot made by sultana');
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
break;
```

How would I fix this code so that each value in the `.addField` lines are replaced with the mentioned users information?

Answer (score 0):

`msg.mentions.members` is a collection, you can get the first user mentioned by `msg.mentions.members.first()`, this is a `GuildMember` instance,

`msg.member` is also a `GuildMember` instance,

although `msg.author` is `User` instance,

converting `GuildMember` to `User`, `<GuildMember>.user`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember

also since you are repeating a lot of the code I would suggest using more conditional operations, and last why are you using switch statements?

Comment: Hi Sevoni, as this is your first answer, try to ask questions to the poster with comments, this way your answer is more imformed and direct.

Comment: I am using switch states to handle each command for the bot, compared to the prefix !